PHP Firebird unable to locate
I'm not being able to locate the pdo_firebird, even tho the file is in the correct directory.
Error message:

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird' (tried: C:\php-8.2.22\ext\pdo_firebird (Imposs├¡vel localizar o m├│dulo especificado), C:\php-8.2.22\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll (Imposs├¡vel localizar o m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0`
(it's in portuguese but it basically says unable to locate the specified module)

Directory SC

I've tried adding the fbclient.dll, checked for typos and I found nothing.

Why is there a folder in your ext directory named pdo_firebird?

Is that fbclient.dll of the right bitness (i.e. if your PHP is 64-bit (very likely), then it has to be a 64-bit DLL as well)? Does the user running PHP actually have read access to php_pdo_firebird.dll?
